# Improve speed of GetUTF8Text functionality in Tesseract

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

It takes around 20 seconds for completing `GetUTF8Text()` functionality in my OCR app.I am using grey scale image. I tried by reducing image size but processing speed and accuracy decreased. Any help to improve speed is greatly appreciated!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701649/improve-tesseract-performance-with-opencv-on-android